# how to return a count of a query with duplicate columns?

Tags: sql, count, teradata

I want to check the number of resulting rows from a statement, but if the statement contains duplicate columns in the select, a `select count(*) from (..the select statement..)` returns an error:

*Duplication of column .... in a table, derived table, view, macro or trigger.*

As an example:

```
select count(*) from
(select t.*, t.tablename from dbc.tablesv t) c
```

since the select statements cannot be modified, as they are processed in bulk, is there a way to make this work?

background: depending on the number of rows returned, i want to switch to utility mode instead of api when unloading.-- this is where the real time is lost, with high data volumes.

thank you

Comment: Why is t.tablename selected twice from dbc.tablesv? If you cannot adjust that, then maybe a `count(1)` instead of a `count(*)` might work. Not sure though.

Comment: So your query doesn't work, and the selects can't be modified.  That pretty much leaves us no way to help you.

Comment: @Andrew Well.. if that is another way of saying that it is not possible to build a wrapper around this statement that removes the duplicates in some shape or form then I guess you have provided a usable answer, thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to run this query? It's almost the same as running the nested Select. Btw, Teradata returns the count of the following result set in the very first message returned to the client (the result is fully created before send to the client)

Comment: Once you duplicated the column name in a query, it's unlikely you will be able to do anything with it as a subquery, aside using it as a straight select.

Comment: it's not about the select, it is about unloading the data. So even if the select takes a few seconds, if that helps to determine to switch to utilitymode instead of api, then we win time.